# bash init script - ambiguous redirect

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to execute a hadoop job from an init script and output to a log file. The commands are as follows

```
log_file="/home/hadoop/log_`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S`.log"
echo $log_file
su - hadoop -c 'java -jar /home/hadoop/testing.jar > $log_file'
```

But I keep getting `-bash: $log_file: ambiguous redirect`.

What is wrong with my statement?

Comment: Tom's comment is exactly right. Within single quotes, variables are **not** expanded.

Comment: @TomFenech that should easily have been an answer :)

Comment: @Felix I went ahead and made it one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using single quotes around your command, so the variable `$log_file` is not being expanded.

#### edit

As clarified by [William Pursell's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080352/bash-init-script-ambigous-redirect#comment37136508_24080698), `$log_file` *is* being expanded but by the wrong shell. See this example (I am using `set -x` to show the commands being evaluated):

```
$ log_file="/dir/file.log"
$ set -x
$ su - -c 'set -x; echo $log_file'     
+ su - -c 'set -x; echo $log_file'     # no expansion of $log_file yet
+ echo                                 # expansion here, no variable $log_file

$ su - -c "set -x; echo $log_file"
+ su - -c 'set -x; echo /dir/file.log' # expansion here, $log_file exists
+ echo /dir/file.log
/dir/file.log
```

#### solution

Try using double quotes instead, so `$log_file` is expanded at the correct point:

```
su - hadoop -c "java -jar /home/hadoop/testing.jar > $log_file"
```

Comment: Or, more accurately, '$log_file' is being expanded by the wrong shell.  (It is expanded by the sh interpreter invoked by hadoop, and in that setting it expands to the empty string.)

Comment: @William thanks a lot for that, I was confused myself as to why it wasn't redirecting to a file named `$log_file` but that explains it perfectly. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Very insightful!